# Fraction program with Fraction class

Tags: c++, rational-numbers

Today I started to make a class called `Fraction`, where the class will act just like a fraction does in real mathematics. I am doing this just for the challenge. So far I only made the addition part, because I wanted to know if anybody had any suggestions for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath> //fmax
#include <vector>
#include <sstream> //stringstream

typedef const std::string constr;

namespace Util
{
    template <typename T>
    constr tostring (T t)
    {
        std::stringstream s;
        s << t;
        return s.str();
    }
}//namespace Util


namespace math
{   
    class Fraction;

    typedef const double cd;
    typedef const long cl;
    typedef std::vector<Fraction> vf;

    class Math //for future use
    {
    private:

    public:

    };

    class Fraction //Fractions cannot be of type 1.2/5.6
    {
    private: //variables

    public: //variables
        long numerator;
        long denominator;
    private: //functions

    public:
        Fraction();
        Fraction(cl numerator_, cl denominator_);
        ~Fraction();
        Fraction operator+ (const Fraction num);
        Fraction operator+ (cl num); //should be possible, for mixed numbers (1 1/2 = 1+1/2=1/2+1)
        cl getcommondemon (cl num1, cl num2);
        vf setcommondemon (const Fraction& num1, const Fraction& num2);
        constr tostring(void);
    };

    Fraction Fraction::operator+ (const Fraction num)
    {
        vf out = Fraction::setcommondemon(*this, num);

        Fraction nn1 = out.at(0);
        Fraction nn2 = out.at(1);

        Fraction output;
        output.numerator = nn1.numerator+nn2.numerator;
        output.denominator = nn1.denominator;

        return output;
    }

    cl Fraction::getcommondemon(cl num1, cl num2)
    {
        if(num1 == num2) return num1;

        int max = fmax(num1, num2);
        int min = fmin(num1, num2);

        if(max % min == 0) //is max a multiple of min? if yes
        {
            return max;
        }
        else
        {
            return max*min;
        }
    }

    Fraction::Fraction()
    {
        numerator = 0;
        denominator = 0;
    }

    Fraction::Fraction(cl numerator_, cl denominator_)
    {
        numerator = numerator_;
        denominator = denominator_;
    }

    Fraction::~Fraction()
    {
        //destructor 
    }

    vf Fraction::setcommondemon(const Fraction& num1, const Fraction& num2)
    {
        vf output;
        Fraction out1;
        Fraction out2;

        if(num1.denominator == num2.denominator)
        {
            output.push_back(num1);
            output.push_back(num2);
            return output;
        }

        bool num1bigger = false;

        long max = 0;
        long min = 0;

        if(num1.denominator > num2.denominator)
        {
            num1bigger= true;
            max = num1.denominator;
            min = num2.denominator;
        }
        else
        {
            min = num1.denominator;
            max = num2.denominator;
        }

        if(max % min == 0) //is max a multiple of min? if yes
        {
            cl multi = max/min;
            if(num1bigger == true)
            {
                out2.numerator = num2.numerator*multi;
                out2.denominator = num2.denominator*multi;
                out1 = num1;
            }
            else
            {
                out1.numerator = num1.numerator*multi;
                out1.denominator = num1.denominator*multi;
                out2 = num2;
            }

            output.push_back(out1);
            output.push_back(out2);
            return output;
        }
        else
        {   
            out1.numerator = num1.numerator*num2.denominator;
            out1.denominator = num1.denominator*num2.denominator;
            out2.numerator = num2.numerator*num1.denominator;
            out2.denominator = num2.denominator*num1.denominator;

            output.push_back(out1);
            output.push_back(out2);

            return output;
        }
    }

    constr Fraction::tostring()
    {
        return Util::tostring(numerator) + "/" + Util::tostring(denominator);
    }

} //namespace math

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    math::Fraction a(1,6);
    math::Fraction b(1,3);
    math::Fraction out = a+b;

    std::cout << out.tostring() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a few pointers:

Do not typedef cv-qualified types. It will confuse everybody who reads your code. Seeing `cl` is really confusing, seeing `const long` is completely understandable. So get rid of the `cd` and `constr`.

If you want to typedef `std::vector<Fraction>`, you need to provide a reasonable name for that type... `vf` while concise conveys precisely zero information. So either do not typedef it, which is fine, or call it `FractionVec` or `Fractions`.

`Fraction` should not have a default constructor. Why would 0/0 be the default?

You either need to provide `operator==` or change the internal representation to keep things to lowerst terms, cause right now `Fraction{1, 2} != Fraction{2, 4}`.

Functions with multiple words in the name should either look like `getCommonDenom` or `get_common_denom`. Running words together having everything be lowercase makes it hard to read. Also, not sure why either of those functions exist, or how it makes sense that a function named `setcommondenom` returns a `vector<Fraction>`??? Also this function is almost certainly wrong given its length, look up Euler's algorithm for gcd and use it.

Rather than defining two separate `operator+` member functions (one of them is wrong, it should take a `const Fraction&` btw), you should create an external friend function and make `long`s implicitly convert to `Fraction`:

```
Fraction() = delete; // no
Fraction(long numer, long denom = 1); // doesn't have to be const
friend Fraction operator+(const Fraction& a, const Fraction& b); // non-member +
```

This lets you do 1 + Fraction{2,3} too!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Below I propose my cleaning to your code. Some comments:

- don't use typedef to spare key-typing: it is best to let the code be verbose
- maybe you can use it for future flexibility (as I did in my sample below). Maybe in the future you want to parameterize your class over integer type
- if you want to define a general purpose class, the less includes the better (less dependencies).
- a fraction can be represented in many different ways. It is a good choice to guarantee that it is always in normalized form. This is achieved by a Fraction::normalize private function. To assure that the user does not violate this, data members should be private. If needed you can write public method to access the values
- if you put a denominator=1 default value in the constructor you have implicit cast from integers to fractions. No need to define two different operator+
- why to use stringbuf to convert fraction to a string? Provide an operator<< to write to a stream and let the user use stringbuf if he really needs a string.
- define a GCD function ones for ever. Check it carefully for boundary cases! (I wrote it quickly, I'm not really sure my version is correct). Once you have a well founded GCD function, always refer to it to compute common denominator and to normalize your fraction.
- don't use const where it is not needed

here is a possible cleanup of your code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace math
{   
  class Fraction //Fractions cannot be of type 1.2/5.6
  {
  private:
    typedef long value_type;
    value_type numerator;
    value_type denominator;

  public:
    Fraction(value_type numerator_, value_type denominator_=1)
      : numerator(numerator_), denominator(denominator_) 
    {
      normalize();
    }

    Fraction operator+ (const Fraction &other) const 
    {
      value_type c = gcd(denominator,other.denominator);
      value_type m_this = denominator / c;
      value_type m_other = other.denominator / c;
      return Fraction(numerator * m_other + other.numerator * m_this,
              denominator * m_other);
    }

    static value_type gcd(value_type a, value_type b);

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Fraction &fraction) 
    {
      return out << "(" << fraction.numerator << "/" << fraction.denominator << ")";
    }

  private:
    void normalize();
  };

  Fraction::value_type Fraction::gcd(value_type a, value_type b) 
  {
    if (a<0) a=-a;
    if (b<0) b=-b;
    for (;;) 
      {
      if (a>b) 
    {
    if (b==0) 
      return a;
    a -= a/b*b;
    } 
      else 
    {
      if (a==0) 
        return b;
      b -= b/a*a;
    }
      }
  }

  void Fraction::normalize() {
    if (denominator<0) 
      {
    denominator = -denominator;
    numerator = -numerator;
      }
    value_type c = gcd(numerator,denominator);
    numerator /= c;
    denominator /= c;
  }

} //namespace math

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    math::Fraction a(1,-6);
    math::Fraction b(1,3);    

    std::cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << a+b << std::endl;
    std::cout << a << " + " << 1 << " = " << a+1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```